# Action Sheets On The iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

On the iPhone I like how action sheets take up the entire width of the screen and you can choose the height of it (so I can include other views). Here is my entire method that creates the action view (you probably on need the las few lines though)...

```
-(void)createActionView {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    UIButton *downHoleScore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    downHoleScore.frame = CGRectMake(93, 75, 35, 35);
    [downHoleScore setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    downHoleScore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    downHoleScore.tag=1;
    [downHoleScore addTarget:self action:@selector(HoleScoreButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [downHoleScore setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Left-Down-Arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [actionSheet addSubview:downHoleScore];

    UIButton *upHoleScore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    upHoleScore.frame = CGRectMake(193, 76, 35, 35);
    [upHoleScore setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    upHoleScore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    upHoleScore.tag=2;
    [upHoleScore addTarget:self action:@selector(HoleScoreButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [upHoleScore setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Right-Up-Arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [actionSheet addSubview:upHoleScore];

    golferScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 70, 45, 45)];
    golferScoreLabel.text = @"0";
    golferScoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    golferScoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkDuster" size: 45.0];
    golferScoreLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    golferScoreLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    golferScoreLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    golferScoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [actionSheet addSubview:golferScoreLabel];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 0, 0);

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 585) inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

How would I edit this to make it look more like an action view on the iPhone?

In this code...

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 585) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

That above is where I think I am messing up how would I make this cover the entire bottom half of the screen on the iPad?

Comment: That is a *very* open ended question. Care to show what you've got, where you want to get, and what specifically you're stuck with?

Comment: @fzwo I added something to the end of my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs on `UIActionSheet`. On iPad, they are presented in popovers.

If you want behavior like on the iPhone, I think you'll have to write your own actionSheet-like view and animations (which is really not that hard, it just takes a little time).

Anyway, presenting actionSheets on an iPad with the full width wouldn't be very good design anyway - you probably don't want buttons that are as wide as the whole screen. I would advise you to rethink your design.

But maybe you don't really want actionSheets. Maybe you only want that nice animation, to present some content of your own like that? That's certainly doable (see above), but then you have asked the wrong question.